# Sudo gets separate PID when starting a command

Tags: linux, bash, docker-daemon

I do not understand why sudo gets a separate PID (e.g. 1620) while starting dockerd (e.g. 1628) with sudo? To which PID should I send SIGTERM to stop the dockerd?

`ps aux | grep dockerd`

[image]

`pstree -ps`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand why `sudo` gets a separate PID (e.g. 1620) while starting dockerd (e.g. 1628) with sudo?

It is just the way that `sudo` works.  It runs the command as a child process because it needs to do things after the child process exits.

You may be able to tweak the `sudo` configs to so that `sudo` doesn't fork a child process.  On my system, `man sudo` says:

> "If no I/O logging plugins are loaded and the policy plugin has not defined a `close()` function, set a command timeout or required that the command be run in a new pty, `sudo` may execute the command directly instead of running it as a child process."

But notice that :

- it says **may** rather than **will**, and
- you are necessarily sacrificing some functionality to achieve this "no fork" behavior.

---

> To which PID should I send SIGTERM to stop the dockerd?

You can send signals to the `sudo` process and they will be relayed to the  `dockerd` process.  That's what `man sudo` says.  Look in the man page's section on signal handling.